# Ubuntustudio is not loading even after its succesfull installation

Tags: boot

I have installed Windows7, later on i installed UBUNTU 12.04. It installed succesfully, but dint show up after restarting at the end.
And as it did not load, i took the chance of installing UBUNTU STUDIO in the same partition(i freed the space, did all the routines).
Its the same now also. JUST MY WINDOWS7 LOADS.
Can anyone please guide me in fixing this issue!

Comment: You could try this http://askubuntu.com/questions/150966/ubuntu-not-showing-on-grub-menu or use a livecd to check where you installed grub.

Comment: Couldn't make any solution out of them, i tried them already.

Answer (score 0):

you must re install grub, the easiest way is to log into a live Ubuntu, then mount your insalled `ubuntu` partition lets say it is mounted at `/media/ubuntu`, then go to terminal and do:

```
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/media/ubuntu sda
```